# How to change datatype of parameter of SQL procedure without changing its body

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's imagine that we have a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[do_some_magic]
   @text nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  -- procedure body
END
```

And now we need to change parameter `@text` datatype from `nvarchar(100)` to `nvarchar(2000)`. Procedure body should not be changed.

How to do this without putting whole procedure body in an `alter` SQL statement?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[do_some_magic]
   @text nvarchar(2000)
-- can we omit following part?
AS
BEGIN
  -- procedure body
END
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  But I'm curious, why you don't want to provide the procedure body?

Comment: Actually procedure body might be modified by user... This SQL should not break it.

Comment: You'll need to specify the body, but you can reconstruct it using dynamic sql by grabbing the definition and altering only the expected pieces. Is that the solution you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a dynamic SQL solution that preserves the current body and only changes the pieces that you need.  Something like this: (depending on how the stored procedure body is you may need to be more clever with the `replace` to avoid changing something else unintentionally)

```
declare @alter nvarchar(max)

SELECT @alter = ROUTINE_DEFINITION
  FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES] as r
  WHERE r.ROUTINE_NAME = 'do_some_magic'
    AND r.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'

SET @alter = replace(replace(@alter,
               'CREATE PROCEDURE','ALTER PROCEDURE'),
               '@text nvarchar(100)','@text nvarchar(2000)')

exec (@alter)
```